# Android Image Management

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-imageview, android-image

I am setting a background Image in my first activity which fits the complete screen in XML code only.
From the first activity user navigates to another activity which does something from an image selected by a user.
Now, my point is since the app loads an image for the user , is it feasible to remove the background image from first activity. And are there chances of app getting crashed if I don't  remove the background image while migrating to the second activity.

Comment: no there is no chance of crashing while you migrate to another activity

Comment: Unless you're loading quite a few images (or the memory on the phone is small), you shouldn't worry too much about switching activities in terms of using too much memory.  If you call `finish()` after `startActivity(intent)`, that will break down the previous activity for you.